# Case Sensitivity Of Datasource Names

Tags: .net, web-config, odbc, dsn

All,

I Have a small confusion about Case sensitivity of ODBC DSN names. Say, you have configured a DSN in your machine with lower case "serverabcd" but in the web.config it's written in upper case "SERVERABCD".

Does that make for a problem OR does the DSN get resolved properly. Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. ODBC DSN names are not case sensitive.

You can easily test this by running odbcad32.exe from your command line. Attempt to create a new DSN connection with the same name, but different case, as an existing connection. You'll be notified that the DSN you're trying to create already exists and whether or not you want to overwrite it.

Answer (score 1):

DSN aren't case sensitive so it will be resolved properly !